# Find Co-domain such that Function becomes always Continuous

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence, continuity

Assume that set $\mathbb{S}$ is co-domain to any function $\mathbb{F}$ and this function is always continuous for any domain which is subset real numbers. What can be $\mathbb S$ ? It is possible if $\mathbb S$ contains only one element but if it is very small interval, then is it possible for function to be always continuous ? If yes, then can we prove it using definition of continuity in terms of convergent sequences ?

Comment: I want to clarify : You want a co-domain $S$ such that all functions $f$ having co-domain $S$ are continuous. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, How big Co-domain we can find such that any function on that co-domain becomes always continuous. I have come across this question when I was going through definition of continuity in terms of convergent sequences.

Comment: Oh I get it. For example, if  the co domain is one point, then every function with that codomain is constant, so will have to be continuous by sequential criteria (by the way, for sequential criteria to apply, you will also need some structure  on $S$, like a topology or something like that, or you can just let $S$ be a subset of real numbers, your choice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the definition of continuity in terms of convergent sequences applies only to metric spaces.

That being said: if $\Bbb S$ is any metric space containing at least two points, then there exists a discontinuous $\Bbb S$-valued function.  If $\Bbb S$ contains any two points $s_1 \neq s_2$, then we can construct such a discontinuous function $f:[0,1] \to \Bbb S$ by defining 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
s_1 & x \neq 0\\
s_2 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
Consider the sequence $x_n = 1/n$ with $n = 1,2,3,\dots$, which satisfies $x_n \to 0$.  We note that $f(x_n) \to s_1$, but $f(0) = s_2$.  So, $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n) \neq f(\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n)$.